# Prove $\frac1{\sqrt{1+a^2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\ge\frac2{\sqrt{1+ab}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

A question asks

> Let $a,b$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
> $$\frac1{\sqrt{1+a^2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\ge\frac2{\sqrt{1+ab}},$$
> if $ab\ge3.$
> and
> $$\frac1{\sqrt{1+a^2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\le\frac2{\sqrt{1+ab}},$$
> if $0< a,b\le1$

---

**My attempt:**

We can assume $a=\tan x,b=\tan y$ for some $x,y\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$. Then,
$$1+ab=\frac{\cos x\cos y+\sin x \sin y}{\cos x \cos y}=\frac{\cos (x-y)}{\cos x \cos y}$$
$$\implies\cos x+\cos y\ge2\sqrt{\frac{\cos x\cos y}{\cos(x-y)}}$$
$$\implies2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\ge2\sqrt\frac{\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)}{2\cos(x-y)}$$

Since both sides are positive, we can square and rearrange to get
$$4\cos^2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos^2\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos(x-y)\ge2\cos(x+y)+2\cos(x-y)$$
$$\implies(1+m)(1+l)l\ge2(m+l)$$
where $l=\cos(x-y),m=\cos(x+y)$. We can rearrange as follows:
$$(1+m)l^2+(m-1)l-2m\ge0$$$$(1+m)l^2-(1+m)l+2ml-2m\ge0$$
$$(1+m)l(l-1)+2m(l-1)\ge0$$$$(l-1)[(1+m)l+2m]\ge0$$
Since $(l-1)<0,$ we just need to prove $(1+m)l+2m\le0$. Now, $ab\ge3$ can be rewritten as $\sin x\sin y\ge3\cos x \cos y$ and thus we have:

$$\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)\ge3\cos(x+y)+3\cos(x-y)$$
or $l\le-2m$. This can be simply modified to $l(1+m)+2m\le-(1+m)2m+2m=-2m^2\le0$. This proves that the inequality holds for $ab\ge3$. I am stuck on how to the prove the second part however. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is obviously not true, if $a=1$ and $b$ is very small, like close to zero small, then the left side is obviously less than the right side. The error was also pointed out under that old question, now ten years later we have the same question with the same mistake.

Comment: @SuzuHirose It asked it as it was stated in the text. While I should have checked it,(and so should the OP in the other qs), mistakes happen. We are after all, human. Thank you for pointing out the error however.

Comment: I'm not particularly criticising you personally I'm just saying that the question is incorrect, before anyone else spends more time looking for a solution.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes it does. Thank you!

Comment: @SuzuHirose I have edited it, so at least the question is correct now.

Comment: At a first glance, substituting $a=e^x$ and $b=e^y$ and using Jensen’S inequality seems attractive

Comment: @person Yes thank you! As a side note, an answer to that effect already exists in the original qs.